# Preventing look-behind/ahead matches overlapping

Tags: regex

I am attempting to match all parts of a string literal contained **between** quotation marks.

`(?<=[\"]).*?(?=(?<=[^\\])[\"]{1})`

The above is a working regex which does this, with one exception, it will of course match all parts of the string literal where there is a quotation mark on the left and the right of it, regardless of quotation pairs.

For example (asterisk indicates matched character):

```
Hello "my" name is "Andy", nice to meet you.`
       ** ********* ****
```

The string literal part " *name is* " here is matched simply because it has a quotation character on either side of it. This is incorrect for what we're looking for. The ideal result would be:

```
Hello "my" name is "Andy", nice to meet you.`
       **           ****
```

In full understanding that this is possible and maybe should be done via writing a state engine - my question would be - in regex terms - if even possible, **how do I prevent a look-behind matching a string literal part previously matched by the look-ahead?**

Comment: this https://regex101.com/r/mN7oE5/2

Comment: \"((?>\\"|.)*?)\" is not viable because this is not matching **between** quotation marks. Therefore look-behind/aheads must be used to determine the quotations presence but not match them.

Comment: Depending on what language you are using, you will be able to convert this to the problem of balanced brackets (in this case - balanced quotes). So what language are you using?

Comment: @ndn I have no preference to program, as this is more of a personal curiosity question than a live project issue. However, preferably it would be a solution that works in .NETs Regex state engine.

Comment: [This](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5e%5b%5e%22%5d*(%22(%5c%5c.%7c%5b%5e%5c%5c%22%5d)*%22%5b%5e%22%5d*)*%22)(%5b%5e%5c%5c%22%5d%7c%5c%5c.)*(%3f%3d%22)&i=Hello+%22m%5c%22y%5c%22%5ca%5c%5c%22+name+is+%22Andy%22%2c+nice+to+meet+you.%60) possibly do what you want, but, IMHO, you better to capture quotation marks and than strip them.

Comment: Fascinating question!

Comment: @AndyJames I updated answer, however working only in Java

Comment: @AndyJames just for information, I discovered by chance, that my regex works also in .NET

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Prelude**

I used Ruby since you said you have *no preference and this is more a personal interest than an actual live product*. However, note that while some of the tricks used here might not work on various regex engines (like the one javascript has) or have different syntax for the same things, there is nothing Ruby specific used here. The same regex will work in Perl, Sublime Text and many more places.

---

But before we begin...

### *DISCLAIMER*: This is not the way to do it! Do not use this in your production codebase!

---

Now that we got that out of the way... This is a pretty interesting problem. Like with any other complex problem, [divide and conquer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divide_and_conquer_algorithms) is the way.

Tricks we are going to use:

1. Named groups

Just as you can create numbered groups with `(group_contents)`, you can define named groups with `(?<group_name>group_contents)`. We don't technically need that, but it will make everything way more comprehensive.

2. Re-execution of group pattern

You can execute the same pattern that was defined before by using `\g<group_name_or_number>`. For example:

```
(?<three_letter_word>\b\w{3}\b) \g<three_letter_word>
```

will match `xyz abc`.

3. Repeat zero times

At first glance, `{0}` might seem useless. However, combined with the two above, it can sort of work like defining functions without executing them. For example:

```
(?<even>[02468]){0}7\g<even>8\<even>9\<even>0
```

will match `7x8y9z0`, where `x`, `y` and `z` are even digits.

4. Drop matched characters

A common restriction in many regex engines is that you can't define lookbehinds with variable length. Even in the ones where you can (like in java), you still have to define maximum length. Therefore, you can't do things like `(?<=x*)`.

`\K` comes to the rescue. What `\K` basically translates to is *drop everything that was matched so far*. So in other words, `(?<=x*)y` can be rewritten as `x*\Ky`.

Armed with these tricks, lets begin.

---

Firstly, let us define a few *"functions"* (using the trick *#3*).

1. **escaped_quote**

An **escaped** quote is a `"` that is preceded by an **odd** number of *back slashes*(`\`). A *back slash* has the special meaning of escaping character, therefore, to match a single *back slash*, we need to escape it with another (aka `\\` = *one literal backslash*).

To match an **even** number of *back slashes*, we can do `\\{2}*` (aka two  *back slashes* zero or more times - **2*n**). To make it **odd**, we just add one more *back slash* - `\\\\{2}*` (**2*n + 1**).

We will also want to say that we want to match all *back slashes* in this sequence. This is because the regex engine will try to find an **even** number of *back slashes* to screw us over, unless we tell it otherwise. `\\\"` will be interpreted as **non escaped** quote, because it can just match `\\"`, ignoring the first slash. In order to not allow this, we will add a negative lookbehind like so: `(?<!\\)\\\\{2}*`

The final definition of our **escaped_quote** *"function"* looks like this:

```
(?<escaped_quote>(?<!\\)\\\\{2}*"){0}
```

2. **non_quoting**

The other thing that we are going to express is something without *meaningful* quotes. This is a sequence of characters, which are escaped quotes or are not quotes at all.

Note that for the *not quotes at all part* we need to add a negative lookahead for **escaped_quote**. This is to make sure we don't eat the first `\` out of an **escaped_quote**, which will leave us with a remaining *not escaped quote*.

```
(?<non_quoting>(?:\g<escaped_quote>|(?!\g<escaped_quote>)[^"])*){0}
```

3. **balanced_quotes**

The last *"function"* that we are going to need is a sequence, that doesn't have unmatched quotes. This can either be something with no *meaningful* quotes at all or with an **even** number of *meaningful* quotes:

```
(?<balanced_quotes>\g<non_quoting>|(?:\g<non_quoting>"\g<non_quoting>){2}+){0}
```

---

With all the prep done, we are ready to match.

We will start with either the beginning of the string or a single quote. The former is obvious. The latter is because our matches will leave one quote behind. `(?:^|")`

**EDIT**: It turned out these are not enough. For the case when last time we matched *empty string*, `\K` will not allow us to stay in the same position and match an *empty string* in the *improvised lookbehind* again. To solve this, we will add another alternative - *empty string*. Note that the order here is important so that we only use this alternative if the other two failed: `(?:^|"|)`

That is followed by a **non_quoting** sequence and everything is dropped (using the *#4* trick) to achieve a lookbehind:

```
(?:^|"|)\g<non_quoting>"\K
```

After that, the thing that we are actually matching is a **non_quoting** sequence:

```
(?:^|"|)\g<non_quoting>"\K\g<non_quoting>
```

Lastly, we have to ensure that after we close the current quote, we are left with **balanced_quotes** til the end of the string:

```
(?:^|"|)\g<non_quoting>"\K\g<non_quoting>(?="\g<balanced_quotes>$)
```

---

### Finally!

We can add our *"function"* definitions and actual matching together, to achieve the final regex:

```
(?<escaped_quote>(?<!\\)\\\\{2}*"){0}(?<non_quoting>(?:\g<escaped_quote>|(?!\g<escaped_quote>)[^"])*){0}(?<balanced_quotes>\g<non_quoting>|(?:\g<non_quoting>"\g<non_quoting>){2}+){0}(?:^|"|)\g<non_quoting>"\K\g<non_quoting>(?="\g<balanced_quotes>$)
```

[**See it in action**](http://rubular.com/r/64nGjLjeDm)

---

**Final thoughts**

A thing to be noted here is that even if some of the features are not supported in your regex engine, you can achieve the same regex by inplacing the function calls. The only thing that is not seen everywhere and you are going to need is `\K`.

I hope it was an interesting learning experience for everyone that read this.

Comment: @iismathwizard, fixed. Just had to change the order of the two alternatives in `non_quoting`.

Comment: hmm what about `\\"s\"s\\"g"` that doesn't seem right

Comment: since you've been so good at finding problems in my regular expressions, mind looking over my recent edit to see if it's good now?

Comment: @iismathwizard, in this case you have 3 (**odd**) number of unescaped quotes. Therefore, the problem is undefined for this case and any behavior is acceptable (as long as there is no infinite processing).

Comment: ahh okay. wasn't exactly sure what behaviour would've been expected to be honest that's why it was more of a question than a comment :p

Comment: ⩗, I may have to report you for using subliminal stimuli.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, is this a thing on SO? xd

Comment: @ndn I really must say, you've put a lot into this question. You've pretty much nailed this and you've given a great description to your solution (made much more elegant with named groups). 
One more bug for you though, :P, putting consecutive quotation marks seems to break balanced quotes after that point.

Comment: @AndyJames, I see. In fact i breaks the next quotes (aka `"" "foo" "bar"` will be matched at *empty string* and `bar`). I'll have to look at this later and come back to you.

Comment: @AndyJames, fixed. This took me almost as much time to understand and to come up with a solution as writing the entire original post. Another strong case for why such things should not be used on production! xd

Comment: If you add for example an one `"` (not pair) it will break some of matched strings, and also it will start to match from the `"` where another citation ends. See [here](http://rubular.com/r/uxt54Wfc0p) , a 9th match, it catch also an empty space after "foo" ...

Comment: @m.cekiera, the problem is not defined for this case as the *quotes* are not not balanced. There must be an **even** number of *meaningful quotes* in the string. Otherwise, how do you determine the string between which *quotes* is *quoted* and/or which *quote* should be ignored? In the case you showed, it just ignores the first quotes and continues with the rest as if nothing happened.

Comment: @ndn if you want to be precise, there is nothing about balanced quotes directly in question. (or about escaping quotes in citation, and multiple escaped backslashes, etc). It is about matching between quotation marks without overlapping. However you are right it is unbalanced, but in my opinion, adding new quote should not change previous result, and the order of occurrence should determine which should be ignored. In my example adding `"` change previous matches. Don't get me wrong, I think your answer is great, excellent prepared and deservedly accepted, congrats

Comment: @m.cekiera, there is a part about escaping quotation and slashes (look at OP's original regex). Also the way I read it, the requirements are to match things between the quotes (without the actual quotes) and to not use the same quotes more than once. By that standard, the regex works just fine. It just ignores the first and not the last quote if there is an **odd** number of those. I could just add a `|` if there was an **odd** number of quotes to begin with and make it match from the first. But I'm not going to do it because it will uglify everything for no actual gain. Thank you though!

Comment: @ndn last thing, for some reason, your regex match the escaped question mark and overlap with another citation, if it is a last match, like [HERE](http://rubular.com/r/fvJMHJTDoA)

Comment: @m.cekiera, this is a valid problem. I'll have to thing about it. It seems to be introduced by the last fix.

Comment: @m.cekiera, fixed. Just had to add one more restriction for the **non_quoting** pattern which wasn't initially needed before the *empty string* fix.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

As a .NET regex support infinite repetitions in lookbehind, the regex:

```
(?<!(.|\n)\G")(?<!(^|[^\\])(\\\\)*\\")(?:(?<=")(?:(?:\\\\|\\"|[^"])+?)(?=")|(?<=")(?="))
```

works even better in .NET than in Java (as using intervals in not best solution).

[DEMO](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3C!(.%7C%5Cn)%5CG%22)(%3F%3C!(%5E%7C%5B%5E%5C%5C%5D)(%5C%5C%5C%5C)*%5C%5C%22)(%3F%3A(%3F%3C%3D%22)(%3F%3A(%3F%3A%5C%5C%5C%5C%7C%5C%5C%22%7C%5B%5E%22%5D)%2B%3F)(%3F%3D%22)%7C(%3F%3C%3D%22)(%3F%3D%22))&i=Hello%20%22my%22%20name%20is%20%22Andy%22%2C%20%22nice%22%20to%20meet%20you.%0D%0A%0D%0AFoo%20%22bar%22%20baz%5C%22%5C%5C%22qux%22.%0D%0A%0D%0A%22%5C%22%22%20%22%5C%22%22%0D%0A%0D%0A%22%22%20%22foo%22%0D%0A%0D%0A%22foo%22%20%22%22%20%22%22%20%22baz%22)

**PREVIOUS ANSWER**

I think I found a way to do it, but only in Java, with a regex:

```
(?<!(.|\n)\G")(?<!(^|[^\\])(\\\\){0,20}\\")(?:(?<=")(?:(?:\\\\|\\"|[^"])+?)(?=")|(?<=")(?="))
```

It is based on my previous attempt, it will work (as far as I know) only in Java because it use in negative lookbehind part, a syntax which is allowed in this language.

Exmplanation of regex:

Regex begin with two negative lookbehind which should ensure that regex will not match from the quotation mark of previous citation, and that it will not match from/to escaped quotation marks.

`(?<!(.|\n)\G")` - this part is responsible for ignoring a quotation marks, which are a part of previous citation. So it is a negative lookbehind for:

- any character `.` also new line `\n` (however if you would use a `DOTALL` mode from Java, the `.` would be enough), followed by;
- `\G` - the end position of previous match or beginning of line, so the regex cannot match after `"` if another match ended on this particular character,
- `"` - quotation mark,

`((?<!(^|[^\\])(\\\\){0,20}\\")` is responsible for ingnoring escaped quotation marks outside of citation, so it is preventing match to start from invalid point. It is nagative lookbehind for:

- `(^|[^\\])` - beginning of a line, or character other than quotation mark (it is to prevent next part to match from middle of backslashes sequence like `\\\\\\\\"xxx"` ), followed by;
- `(\\\\){0,20}` - the zero or more (up to 20) sets of two backslashes (to ensure that it is escaped quatation mark), followed by;
- `\\` - single escaping backslash,

In the most of languages, the lookbehind is zero-length and it need to have fixed length, so it is not allowed to use quatifires or intervals in it(`+`,`*`,`?`,`{2,4}`). However in Java it is possible to use `?` and interval with min and max lenght. So, the 20 in `(\\\\){0,20}` is a max value, it could be more, but I suppose no one will use more than (or even nearly) 20 double backslashes in a row. But still it is something it is worth to remember. I this regex, this construction is used to match even numbers of backslashes, and determine if backslash before quotation mark is esceped character or to escape following character.

This part is followed by alternative for matching quotation with content, and without any content. The last part (for matching without content) is a much simpler one: `(?<=")(?="))`, it should match a point between two valid quotation marks, but because of `(?<!(.|\n)\G")` part, it will not match the point beetween for example the second and third quotation mark in a row (like `"""`). The first alternative is a little bit more complex:

`(?<=")(?:(?:\\\\|\\"|[^"])+?)(?=")` match a string which is preceeded and followed by quotation mark. It consist:

- `(?<=")` - positive lookbehind for quotation mark,
- `(?:(?:\\\\|\\"|[^"])+?)` - an alternative explained below,
- `(?=")` - positive lookahead for quotation mark,

The `(?:\\\\|\\"|[^"])+?)*` is an alternative for:

- `\\\\` - to backslashes, it is important to match it before `\"`, to avoid matching case like `\\"` as `\"`,
- `\\"` - quotes mark and backslash, important to match before `[^"]`, so `\"` will be matched as part of a quote;
- `[^"]` anything that is not a quote sign

[Ideone demonstration in Java.](https://ideone.com/e39quh)

[Regex demonstration on RegexPlanet](http://fiddle.re/n6faw6) - click Java

Comment: This breaks for `"\\"`.

Comment: This is really good but I modified it a bit to work better. I felt it would be wrong to edit into my answer since I never even knew about `\G`. Here's what I did. Feel free to edit your answer with it: `(?<!.\G")(?<=")(?>\\.|.)*?(?=")`

Comment: @ndn thank you for comment, indeed it did't match `\\`.

Comment: @iismathwizard thank you, I appreciate this, but I would not use it anyway, because: 1) it is not my answer, 2) and it also has some flaws [demo](https://regex101.com/r/kY1kB3/1), but atomic grouping in great idea.

Comment: @m.cekiera oh! I didn't see those flaws. Thanks for pointing them out :o

Comment: It will break for `"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\""`. Using `{0,20}` is like trying to cheat the regex devil. xd

Comment: As I wrote in answer _20 in (\\\\){0,20} is a max value, it could be more, but I suppose no one will use more than (or eave nearly) 20 double backslashes in a row._ . So yes, it will break with 20x\\, so make it `(?:\\\\){0,999999999}\\")` and try to wrote so many pairs of backslashes. I don't think that this is problem, as such imput is just not very likely. I aware that this is not very elegant way, but it works with most probable input, and I think there is no other regex way in Java

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**:

I think this is right now.

```
(?<!.\G")(?<="|\\\\")(?<![^\\]\\")((?>\\.|[^"])*?)(?=")
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pY1yQ6/1)

Comment: better `"((?>\\"|[^"])*)"`

Comment: Because this is not matching **between** quotation marks. Therefore look-behind/aheads must be used to determine the quotations presence but not match them.

Comment: @AndyJames *I am attempting to match all parts of a string literal contained between quotation marks.* I'm not sure I understand then

Comment: Keyword is **between** not including.

Comment: Well then this should be fine because it's not capturing the quotation marks.

Comment: @iismathwizard, it does. It doesn't include it in the match group, but it is part of the match...

Comment: I don't understand this. How does the second `\K` not remove everything matched so far and only the last `"`. Could you explain?

Comment: @ndn ahh it doesn't. I'll fix that. i guess the best I can do is not match the first quote but I can't do much about the second

Comment: @AndyJames how's this?

Comment: @iismathwizard, doesn't work. Try it with `"foo"bar"baz"`. Should have matched `foo` and `baz` instead.

Comment: @ndn I was hoping that we would expect a space or comma there.. not sure if this is possible

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following as a general approach. I've added `puts` statements in the code to show what's happening.

```
str = 'Hello "my" name is "Andy", nice to meet "Sally"'

r = /
    (       # start capture group 1
    .*?     # match >= 0 characters lazily 
    (?<=\") # match " in a positive lookbehind
    (.*?)   # match >= 0 characters lazily in capture group 2
    (?=\")  # match " in a positive lookahead
    .       # match one character
    )       # close capture group 1
    /x      # extended mode

a = []
s = str.dup
loop do
  break a unless s =~ r
  puts
  puts "$1 = |#{$1}|"
  puts "$2 = |#{$2}|"
  a << $2
  puts "a  = #{a}"
  s = s[$1.size..-1]
  puts "s  = |#{s}|"
end
```

```
$1 = |Hello "my"|
$2 = |my|
a  = ["my"]
s  = | name is "Andy", nice to meet "Sally"|

$1 = | name is "Andy"|
$2 = |Andy|
a  = ["my", "Andy"]
s  = |, nice to meet "Sally"|

$1 = |, nice to meet "Sally"|
$2 = |Sally|
a  = ["my", "Andy", "Sally"]
s  = ||
  #=> ["my", "Andy", "Sally"]
```

The key here is to match one character following the positive lookahead. Without it the code would return:

```
["my", " name is ", "Andy", ", nice to meet ", "Sally"]
```

Notice that the values of `$1` show that the character matched after the positive lookahead is not included in the match. Moreover, `', nice to meet "Sally"'` is matched, even though `'Sally'` is not followed by a character.

I didn't understand what `.` is matching? @ndd explained that it was matching `"` in `s`, which makes perfect sense considering that lookarounds are zero-width.

Comment: The `.` is matching the closing `"` of the current match. Without it, the `.*?` at the start matches just the `"` of the last match and it's basically like splitting the string by `"` (aka only one `"` will be consumed by each match and the closing `"` is used in the next match).